# C++ How to make text health bar

Tags: c++

I'm making something in C++, a text game to be precise, anyways I was wondering how would I make a Text Health Bar. '{' is the starting, '}' is the ending point of the health bar, ':' is the health so it makes something like {:::::::}. So I want the }, to stay where it is when the health is subtracted. How would you go about doing this?

What I have tried before was repeating a ':', based on the Health divided by your strength, but the '}' would follow the ':'. I had attempted to have a for loop to repeat the amount of spaces - health, and printing out a the character ' ' depending on how much spaces there should be. But none of these methods have worked.

So how would you Replace the colons I take out with spaces to keep a uniform length.

Comment: What have you tried, and what about it didn't work? Consider [edit]ing your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: Generally to make something you need to try making it.

Comment: If you need to reposition the cursor, you will need to use a *cursor positioning* library.  You may be able to use `\r` to return the carriage to the beginning of the line, but depends on the console (terminal) emulation.

Comment: Do you know how to write a character to the console?  Do you know how to write a loop?  What part of this are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Replace the colons you take out with spaces to keep a uniform length.

Comment: Thats what I need help with. I don't really know on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print `:` for each strength point and fill the remaining with spaces (capacity).  There are several methods.

**Method 1:  The loop**

```
cout << '{';
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i)
{
  if (i < strength)
  {
    cout << ':';
  }
  else
  {
    cout << ' ';
  }
}
```

**Method 2: String of repeated characters**

```
const std::string strength_text(strength, ':');
const std::string filler_text(capacity-strength, ' ');
cout << '{';
cout << strength_text << filler_text;
cout << '}';
```

**Method 3: Setting field width**

```
const std::string strength_text(strength, ':');
cout << '{';
cout << setw(capacity) << strength_text;
cout << '}';
```

You should research the `setw` modifier to see if it performs a right justified or left justified fill.

Other methods involve cursor positioning, which requires an external library.