# I made a rougelike game in visual studio and i want to display the players health

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I made a player class which holds everything related to the player. Can I call player.h in my GameSystem.h and do cout your health and go player._health. Am I doing something wrong cause it says class player type name is now aloud.

```
class Player
{
public:
Player();
void init(int level, int health, int attack, int defense, int experience);

int attack();
int takeDamage(int attack);



// Set Player funtion
void setPosition(int x, int y);

void addExperience(int experience);

void setHP(int hp);

void setMaxHP(int hp);

// Get player position
void getPosition(int &x, int &y);


private:
// Player porperties
int _level;
int _health;
int _maxHp;
int _attack;
int _defense;
int _experience;

// Player Position
int _x;
int _y;


};
```

I want to call the players health in my GameSystem.cpp how would I go about doing that.

```
#include "GameSystem.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>


// Constructor which sets up the game
GameSystem::GameSystem(string levelFilename)
{
_player.init(1, 100, 10, 10, 0);

_level.load(levelFilename, _player);

system("pause");
}

void GameSystem::playGame() 
{
bool isDone = false;

while (isDone != true)
{
    _level.print();
    playerMove();
}
}

void GameSystem::playerMove()
{
char input;
printf(" Enter a move command (w/s/a/d: ");
input = _getch();
cout << " Your Health:" << Player._health;

_level.movePlayer(input, _player);


}
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.  What have you tried so far?  Also please re-read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You declare `_health` as `private`, so why expect to be able to use that outside of member functions or `friend` classes?

Comment: I have tried to cout the players house in my player move function but it tells me class player type name is not allowed even though I included player.h

Comment: Also of note: if you get a compiler error, make sure you specify the *exact* error message and the line it pertains to.

Comment: Please study the concept of a [mcve].

Comment: ***class player type name is not allowed even though I included player.h*** My guess is you have a circular include path. With that said please post the exact text of your errors instead of paraphrasing. Get that from the Output tab of Visual Studio.

Comment: Just a tip: If you are using "using namespace std;" stop now. It can, in the future lead to weird behaviur because of name clash. And using namespace * is not a good practice to import all the namespace.

Comment: See also [How to make text health bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703037/c-how-to-make-text-health-bar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably understands the concept of private/public. If not, you should understand that private means that, everything on that scope cannot be accessed from outside. For your problem you should create a public method, like your getPosition that returns the health, like

```
int getHealth(){ return this->_health; }
```

Study private and public. C++ is a complex language, even if, for now, it does not seems like that hard it will get hard, specially if you are trying to write a game.

Comment: nitpick:  accessor methods like this should be tagged const, e.g. int getHealth() const {...}

Comment: nitpick:  The `this->` syntax is not needed in this case.  It is only needed when parameters or variables have the same name as class members (use renaming to avoid the `this->` syntax).

Comment: I agree on both. I didn't mentioned const on get because it seems that the user is having problems with the idea of public/private, so to avoid confusion. The this-> is just because I am used to use this, even if there is no another variable with the same name. There will be no issue for the compiler because of the this->. And about causing confusion, this only depends on the standard that people are using.